# Can't attach clothes and hair to body (bones)

Tags: mesh, armature, bezier-curves, parent

As you can imagine I am a beginner with Blender.

I am modelling a character for a game and I can't attach the hair (full geometry, no particles), and the clothes to the character, and as a result, when I animate, the body moves, but the clothes remain in the middle of the scene.

I saw a lot of people having this problem, but mine is a little bit different, I joined all the hair curves together, transformed them into a mesh, and joined the resulting mesh with the body. Same with the clothes and items. And now, if I select let's say the skirt, it selects everything with a green outline.

I mention that I imported the human (with eyes and eyelashes) from MakeHuman as a .mhx2 with the Default pose.

I am really confused right now, and that's because I tried all the methods I found, and none of them worked for me, except for one, but I can't remember what I did and what hotkeys I pressed, and what actually happened, and it only worked for 95% of the hair.

If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I would also really appreciate if you clean up my model a little bit, cause I was quite disorganized.

My model: https://www.mediafire.com/?jbb8qcmizbq8o34

Comment: Have you weight painted the newly added parts of you mesh?

Comment: I solved it this way, but ehen I asked I didn't know hoe to do it. Thank you for guiding me.